# Wordpress: Link a post to posts of another category manually

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, posts

I have an 'events' post type. I have another category called 'Speakers' and it has posts which are speakers.

When creating an event I need to select the speakers for each event through backend. I need to give an interface so that the admin could select the speakers for the event.

Comment: Show us your research, post your code and ask exact problem statement. You cannot ask us to write code for your requirement.

Comment: You can add a custom-field for your "events" post type. See http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-metabox-custom-post-type for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I was initially thinking of adding a custom field with the speakers post id comma separated. But that is going to be very difficult for a non-technical person. I will try to add a meta box with add more option to select speakers from the other category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [AdvancedCustomFields-Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). With this you can build a "relationship" between your post type 'events' and the 'speakers'. This way you can choose the 'speakers' on every 'event'.

The Plugin is well documented. See for yourself how it works:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I used this method so that it is easier to manage future changes as well

Comment: My pleasure. ACF is a great tool I use on almost every WP-installation. Dealing with the built-in 'metas' is always a little unflexible so I was glad to find ACF one day.

Comment: I would say the only drawback to using a plugin would be relying on a plugin for your core site to work properly. If the makers of the plugin decide to change or deprecate something, then you'll have to update each of the pages that you used the code on. And when a plugin makes a significant change like ACF did recently, you might end up losing some functionality completely or be left unable to update the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on what you need, it's hard to give a code example, but the idea would be to set up a meta box for that custom post type that runs a query for all speakers and displays them in a select box.

Adding Meta Boxes:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Running a Query:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
(this is for WP_Query, but there are also others, like `get_posts`, that you can use)

**GENERAL STEPS**

- Create meta box for events custom post type
- Within the meta box, put a select box with the query results for speaker custom post type
- Make sure to save data within meta box on post's save
- Get and display meta box data in template/page

If you could post more information, I can add some example code to help you out.

Comment: I had used this technique but if I need to add any more fields then I would need to again update the code. So I went with the method suggested by @zork media. Thank you for your suggestion